# Convert observable to a variable

Tags: angular, observable

I am retriving some data from firebase via **observable** in `valueChanges` method.

```
this.authService.getUser().subscribe(
      user => {
        this.studentDetailsService.readStudentDatabase( user.uid ).subscribe( temp => {
          this.student = temp as StudentDetails ;
        });
      }
    );
```

but i cant use `this.student` objects out side the Observable like this

```
this.authService.getUser().subscribe(
      user => {
        this.studentDetailsService.readStudentDatabase( user.uid ).subscribe( temp => {
          this.student = temp as StudentDetails ;
        });
      }
    );

    this.name = this.student.firstName;
```

when im doing this console shows `this.name` is undefined.

how to solve this ?? **how can i use those retrived values outside the observable ?**

Comment: Why do you need to set it outside of subscribe function?

Comment: Subscribe inside subscribe isn't recommended but anyway you should be able to access it outside since you're storing that in a class property. Make sure temp inside subscribe isn't undefined.

Comment: So how to do this without subscribe inside subscribe ?

Comment: Use one of the operators that unwraps an observable, e.g. `.pipe(flatMap(...))`.

Comment: This has been closed and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call given as answering this question. While I agree this does touch on the asynchronous aspect, it ignores how to achieve this with Rxjs. This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
studenDetails$ = this.authService.getUser().pipe(
  switchMap(user => 
     this.studentDetailsService.readStudentDatabase(user.id)));
```

Then you can output the student details in your template using the async pipe rather than using subscribe.

```
{{ studenDetails$ | async | json }}
```

You can do something like the following, but **I would recommend using using the above solution instead**

```
this.authService.getUser().pipe(
  switchMap(user => 
     this.studentDetailsService.readStudentDatabase(user.id).pipe(
       tap(student => this.student = student),
       map(student => student.firstName),
       tap(firstName => this.firstName = firstName))).subscribe();
```

This will set the class field `firstName` to the students first name.